# Adding multiple columns to a data.table, where column names are held in a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I want to add a large number of columns to a data.table in R.
The column names are held in a vector `a`. How to do it?

```
x <- data.table(a=1,b=1)
f <- function(x) {list(0)}
```

The following works:

```
x <- x[, c("col1","col2","col3") := f()]
```

but the following doesn't:

```
a <- c("col1","col2","col3")
x <- x[, a := f()]
```

How do I add the columns defined within `a`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to make that work, you have to wrap the `a` in `()` like this:

```
x[, (a) := f()]
```

this results in the following datatable:

> ```
> > x
>    a b col1 col2 col3
> 1: 1 1    0    0    0
> ```

Explanation: when you use `x[, a:=f()]` you assign the outcome of `f()` to column `a` (`data.table` allows this for convenience). Thus `a` is treated as a name in this occasion. When you use `(a)`, `a` is treated as an expression (in this case a vector of column names).

Furthermore: you don't need to assign this to `x` again with `x <-` as the datatable is updated by reference because the `:=` operator is used.