# Appending a vector to a data.table as separate new columns, vector-recycling single values

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to add a vector to a `data.table` with each name of the vector's elements corresponding to a new column, and the value repeated based on the vector's element value.

So given:

```
x <- data.table(a=1:2, b=3:4)
v <- c(c=5, d=6)
```

I'm seeking a result of:

```
data.table(a=1:2, b=3:4, c=5, d=6)
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 6
# 2: 2 4 5 6
```

**Things I tried:**

`cbind` adds the vector as a single column:

```
cbind(x, v)
#    a b v
# 1: 1 3 5
# 2: 2 4 6
```

Using the approach from [Adding multiple columns to a data.table, where column names are held in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32665995/1840471) also vectorizes wrongly (horizontally rather than vertically):

```
x[, (names(v)) := v]
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 5
# 2: 2 4 6 6

x[, (names(v)) := list(v)]
# Same as above.
```

Comment: It works fine with `vlist <- list(c=5, d=6)`.

Comment: Instead of saying "with single values", the term you wanted was "vector-recycling single values"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this without looping too

```
x[, names(v) := as.list(v)]
x
#   a b c d
#1: 1 3 5 6
#2: 2 4 5 6
```

Comment: Ah, `as.list` instead of `list`, thanks. Why are parens not needed around `names(v)`? It works with them as well.

Comment: @MaxGhenis It may be better to use parens as it is more general i.e. `cols <- names(v);x[, (cols) := as.list(v)]1

Comment: @Max Really, `v` should be specified using `v = list(c = ...)` from the start. Table rows are (ordered) tuples not vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Looping works:

```
for (i in seq_along(v)) x[, (names(v)[i]) := v[i]]
```

Result:

```
x
#    a b c d
# 1: 1 3 5 6
# 2: 2 4 5 6
```

Comment: A better `for` loop might be `for (name in names(v)) set(x, j = name, value = v[name])`.